# Does updating an app delete the cookies of a UIWebView?

Tags: ios, cookies, uiwebview, google-analytics

I'm building an iOS app that uses a `UIWebView` to show most of it's content. I want to use Google Analytics (Web) to track the user behavior in the `UIWebView`. Will the cookie be deleted once a user updates their app? Can I somehow keep it?

Comment: It should not. It upgrading an app doesn't mess with the stored data.

Answer (score 0):

It should not!.

However NSCookie default storage places not revealed.But from IOS4 you can provide your storage location using

```
– initWithStorageLocation:
```

Method. Documents Folder persists across updates.So you can make sure it persists by storing in documents folder.

Comment: By default the UiWebView stores the cookie in Library/Cookies. Do I understand you correctly that I need to store it in the documents folder? But will the UiWebView still recognize it?

Comment: @SvenKoerbitz.   When you initiate your NSCookie with the storage location using the method, your webview recognize it.